# Powershell - Extract timestamp

Tags: windows, powershell, timestamp

i am completely new to Powershell and I am trying to create a script to extract the timestamp for the string found in a log file. There are log files everyday and it should select the latest file. It then looks for a string in that file. Now, where it finds the string it should also return a timestamp where the string is located. I am only able to complete the first part and struggling with the 2nd bit. My script is in no way optimal but it is a start. Any help is appreciated.

```
Set-Location -Path "O:\xyz\0502251\logs"
$latest = (Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter 'async_SPARKLE_ONITE_*.log' | Sort-Object CreationDate -Descending | Select-Object -last 1).fullname
$pattern = "Successfulyl finished running psp_dba_maint_4"
$search = (Get-Content $latest | Select-String -Pattern "psp_dba_maint_4" | Select-Object -last 1)
    if($search)
    {
   
    "The overnight completed at:" 
    }
    else
    {
        "Do something"
    }
```

This looks for the latest file and extracts the string. Now Just want to know at what time this log was generated.

[image]

The log is:

```
Connection 1
Server message: 2022-10-15 23:56:07:020
Message number: 0, Severity 10, State 1, Line 126
Procedure 'psp_dba_locklogin'
Message String: -----> login SPRK_SVC_IRISS logged in at 23:55:45 running SRI.exe:AWAITING COMMAND on rptSPARKLE from host da-pvrep02 is still active


Connection 1
Server message: 2022-10-15 23:56:07:020
Message number: 0, Severity 10, State 1, Line 126
Procedure 'psp_dba_locklogin'
Message String: -----> login SPRK_SVC_IRISS logged in at 23:55:45 running SRI.exe:AWAITING COMMAND on rptSPARKLE from host da-pvrep05 is still active


Connection 1
Server message: 2022-10-15 23:56:07:020
Message number: 0, Severity 10, State 1, Line 126
Procedure 'psp_dba_locklogin'
Message String: -----> login SPRK_SVC_IRISS logged in at 23:55:39 running SRI.exe:SELECT on rptSPARKLE from host da-pvrep02 is still active


Connection 1
Server message: 2022-10-15 23:56:07:020
Message number: 0, Severity 10, State 1, Line 126
Procedure 'psp_dba_locklogin'
Message String: -----> login SPARKLE_CAI logged in at 23:55:37 running SPARKLE ESB (pooled):AWAITING COMMAND on A_uatSPK from host DA-UVESB01 is still active


Connection 1
Server message: 2022-10-15 23:56:07:020
Message number: 0, Severity 10, State 1, Line 355
Procedure 'psp_dba_dbrefresh'
Message String: Setting PrivShield on SPRKSZCBS OUT OF maintenance mode


Connection 1
Server message: 2022-10-15 23:56:07:022
Message number: 0, Severity 10, State 1, Line 362
Procedure 'psp_dba_dbrefresh'
Message String:  


Connection 1
Server message: 2022-10-15 23:56:07:022
Message number: 0, Severity 10, State 1, Line 364
Procedure 'psp_dba_dbrefresh'
Message String:    - Refresh 2 complete


Connection 1
Server message: 2022-10-15 23:56:07:028
Message number: 0, Severity 10, State 1, Line 42
Procedure 'psp_dba_maint_4'
Message String: Successfulyl finished running psp_dba_maint_4
```

This has different values in files generated everyday. So it should look for the latest file and return the result as **`The overnight completed at: 23:56`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a variant using the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) statement to efficiently process the file line-by-line and test each line to match given [RegEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2) patterns:

```sh
$found = switch -File $latest -RegEx {
    '\d\d:\d\d' { $timestamp = $matches[0] }
    'Successfulyl finished running psp_dba_maint_4' { $true; break }
}

if( $found ) {
    "The overnight completed at: $timestamp"
}
else {
    "Not found"
}
```

- `$found = switch ...` assigns the output of the switch statement to the variable. The output will be `$true` if the pattern has been found.
- `\d\d:\d\d` searches for the time (first occurence of a pair of two digits separated by `:`) within the current line. The [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#matches) `$matches[0]` then gives the matched value, similar to the RegEx `-match` operator. For a detailed explanation of the RegEx pattern and the ability to experiment with it, see this [Regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/ESBMxX/2).
- Although there is no `$false` output of the `switch` statement, an empty output evaluates to `$false` in a boolean context (in this case the `if` statement), so if the pattern isn't found, the `else` branch will be entered.
- There is a typo in `Successfulyl` which I just copied from your example ;)

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate it. It worked using this. But can you please explain or point me towards what the regex used in this mean.

Comment: @RockyJohanson I've added a link to a [Regex101 demo page](https://regex101.com/r/ESBMxX/1) that explains it. Let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [zett42's helpful `switch`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74082870/45375):

A [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) solution, as you attempted, *is* possible, via the `-Context` parameter, which allows you to capture the lines *surrounding* a matching line as well:

```
$time = 
  Select-String -LiteralPath $latest -Pattern 'psp_dba_maint_4' -Context 3 | 
  Select-Object -Last 1 |
  ForEach-Object {
    # Extract and output the 'HH:mm' part of the timestamp from 
    # the 3rd line above the match (the first element in the pre-context array)
    $_.Context.PreContext[0] -replace '^.+ (..:..).+$', '$1'
  }

if ($time) {
  "The overnight completed at: $time" 
} else {
  'Do something'
}
```

Note:

- It is much more efficient to pass the file *path* of the target file to `Select-String`, via `-LiteralPath`, than it is to pass the file's *content*, line by line, via `Get-Content`.

  - If you had assigned the whole *file-info object* ([`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo)), as emitted by `Get-ChildItem`, to `$latest`, you could alternatively have provided it via the *pipeline*: `$latest | Select-String ...`
- The type of the match-information objects that `Select-String` emits is [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo).
- The [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace` operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) is used to extract (part of) the time-of-day string from the context line.

  - For an explanation of the above regex (and substitution, where `$1` refers to the first and only capture group, `(...)`), see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/NGewbk/1).

Answer (score 1):

As you need to get the Time information only related to the procedure psp_dba_maint_4 you can do:

```
#Remove empty lines, join strings and split string at "connection 1" = you keep the related information together. Next parse the array of strings for the string which matches "psp_dba_maint_4" and after that extract dateTime

$null = (((Get-Content $latest | ?{$_}) -join $null) -split "connection 1" | ?{$_ -match "psp_dba_maint_4"}) -match '\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'
$Search = $matches[0]
if($search){
    "The overnight completed at: $search" 
}
else{
    "Do something"
}
```

Alternatively you could parse the log an create objects, e.g.:

```
$obj = @(
    Get-Content $latest | ?{$_} | %{
        #If string is connection 1 initialize hashtable/create object
        If ($_ -match 'connection 1'){
            If ($attrsHT){
                new-object -typename psobject -Property $attrsht
            }
            $attrsHt = @{}
        }
        Else {
            #replace Procedure with Procedure, replace ": " with | and split at |
            $split = (($_ -replace "Procedure","Procedure:") -replace ": ","|") -split "\|"
            #add key and value to hashtable
            $attrsht.add($split[0],$split[1])
        }
    }
)
```

gives you the array $obj containing the loginformation:

```
$obj[0] | fl *

Procedure      : 'psp_dba_locklogin'
Message String : -----> login SPRK_SVC_IRISS logged in at 23:55:45 running SRI.exe:AWAITING COMMAND on
                 rptSPARKLE from host da-pvrep02 is still active
Server message : 2022-10-15 23:56:07:020
Message number : 0, Severity 10, State 1, Line 126
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution to add to the rest.

```
if ($found = Get-Content -Path $latest -ReadCount 7 | %{
        if ($_ -match 'Setting PrivShield on SPRKSZCBS OUT OF maintenance mode')
        {
            [regex]::Match($_,'\d\d:\d\d').Value
        }
    }
) { "The overnight completed at: $found" }
else { 'not found' }
```

On another note, `$latest` contains the oldest file and not the newest. Specifying `-Descending` in your `Sort-Object` brings the most current files to the top. So, when you select the last one via `-Last 1`, that is the oldest file and not the newest.